# Overlay CSS Element on top of Jquery. Z-Index?

Tags: jquery, html, css, overlay, z-index

I want to overlay a CSS element on top of some Jquery stuff going on in the background.

I want that white box to be on top, but the jquery popup words to come up in the grey side sections. 
So that white box should completely cover up any words popping up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try add this class `.contentsarea {z-index: 1;position: relative;}`

Comment: You are a god amongst men. Thank you.